# What is the largest number k < 100,000 such that k has an odd number of factors?

Tags: problem-solving

so i do not know how to solve this problem and is confused on a method to find odd number of factors.
How can I find the odd number of factors for a number that high?

Comment: Factors _usually_ come pairwise.  What type of numbers have an odd number of factors?

Comment: @AndrewChin This qualifies as an answer. If you post it as an answer, I will upvote.

Comment: "Divisor" would be a better name than "factor". First, it could lead to a confusion with the prime factors and second , $1$ is usually not considered as a "factor" , sometimes neither the number itself.

Answer (score 3):

The number is $\lfloor \sqrt{100000}\rfloor^2$. Squares and only squares have odd number of divisors.